# Java Bukkit OOP

Tags: java, oop, minecraft, bukkit

Can someone tell me why this isn't working?
It's a basic OOP function. It works, but for some reason it stopped working.

```
public class InfoboardManager {
    private MainInfoboard mi;
    private Player p;

    public InfoboardManager(Player p) {
        this.p = p;
    }

    public MainInfoboard getMainInfoboard() {
        return mi;
    }

    public class MainInfoboard {
        public void echoName() {
            System.out.println("His name is " + p.getName());
        }
    }

}
```

I'm calling it like this:

```
    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
        InfoboardManager ib = new InfoboardManager(e.getPlayer());
        MainInfoboard mi = ib.getMainInfoboard();
        mi.echoName();
        e.setJoinMessage(null);
    }
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Where is the `MainInfoBoard` initialized? With only your current code it will propably throw an `NullPointerException`. (Which you should be able to solve pretty easy I guese?). Besides "not working" isn't a proper description of what went different than what you expected. Please include what you expected, and what result you got, including code, images and stacktraces if relevant.

Comment: @n247s I want to print players name to console. So when player join, console will write for ex.: His name is eNcoo.

Comment: You're not calling `echoName()` anywhere.

Comment: @Esko thanks for your answer. :D I'm calling it, but I copied it badly. It's edited now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize your `MainInfoboard`.

```
public class InfoboardManager {
private MainInfoboard mi;
private Player p;

public InfoboardManager(Player p) {
    this.p = p;
    this.mi = new MainInfoboard();
}

public MainInfoboard getMainInfoboard() {
    return mi;
}

public class MainInfoboard {
    public void echoName() {
        System.out.println("His name is " + p.getName());
    }
}
}
```

If it is a `NullPointerException`. You might want to tell us the Error you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

Your `private MainInfoboard mi;` property of class `InfoboardManager`is never initialized